# ServiceStack Silverlight service client

Tags: silverlight, servicestack

I followed instructions at https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SilverlightServiceClient, but I am not sure if this tutorial is valid any more. For one, I don't get any ServiceClient at all. Second, I am not sure if I need to build it as per code that is under "The ServiceClient Implementation" or if it is already part of nuget package. Yes, I installed nuget package. Please advise.

Comment: I just experienced the same thing. I installed the ServiceStack NuGet package in my SL 5 project, but can't resolve the 'ServiceClient' type at all. Hang in there. I'm sure they'll help us out soon. I've used ServiceStack before and the ones maintaining the codebase have been very responsive and helpful so far.

Comment: I added ServiceClient type as per documentation in my application, and changed it to use ServiceStack's serializer, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the ServiceStack assembly in Object Browser, it looks like there are multiple flavors of ServiceClientBase. It's possible the tutorial is out of date, as I don't see any derived types named simply 'ServiceClient'. Perhaps we're to use the AsyncServiceClient instead?